# Enable Guard Malloc, don't download files using NSURLSession

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I'm comparing two ways to create a new NSURLSession:

1.

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
```

2.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration;
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5;
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10;
    NSURLSession* session=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
```

When Guard Malloc is enabled, the first method can be used to complete a download, but the second method timed out. I increased the timeout length, but it didn't help.

If Guard Malloc is disabled, both methods of creating the session can be used to complete downloads successfully.

**why?**

Comment: Thank you , it is a big help to improve my English. `@speckledcarp`

Comment: Are you retaining the newly created session properly?  Normally you'd assign the session to a property somewhere rather than a local variable.  If you aren't doing that, the differences in timing caused by Guard Malloc might be causing it to get autoreleased before the first request starts, in which case it won't retain itself.  Just a guess, though.

Comment: Yeah,maybe. I will debug it. thank you.@dgatwood